# Carthrob Get custom order data field value

Tags: custom-fields, checkout

I am using cartthrob
I have created a custom field called notes

I am working on a pre authorize hook

I can retrieve the current order details like
$this->EE->cartthrob->cart->order('payment_gateway')

but if i try and retrieve my  custom field data nothing is returned even though the data is stored in the order channel entry after i submit the order

when i out put the custom data there is no mention of my custom field

"custom_data"]=> array(0) { } ["subscription"]=> bool(false) ["subscription_options"]=> array(0) { } ["payment_gateway"]=> string(6) "stripe" ["subscription_id"]=> bool(false)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment your question (not enough reputation), I just wanted to remind you that you can use `{exp:cartthrob:debug_info}` to display cartthrob debug data to see if your fields are correctly set. http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/debug_info/index.html